# Как вывести несколько значений параметра

Tags: c#

Есть задание, в котором надо вывести все значения примера x+y, но могу вывести только одно. Причём из двух возможных значений выводится либо одно, либо другое. Как вывести два этих значений одновременно?

```
var random = new Random(); 
int x, y; 
do 
{ 
    x = random.Next(1, 9); 
    y = random.Next(1, 9); 
} while (x * 10 + y != (x+y)+Math.Pow((x+y),2));
Console.WriteLine($"{x}{y}");
Console.WriteLine($"{x}{y}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Суть вопроса не понятна абсолютно. Дополните Ваш вопрос, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Напишу всё задание: Найти все двузначные числа, такие, если до суммы цифр этого числа
прибавить квадрат этой суммы, то получим это же число. Именно все двузначные числа, у меня получается вывести только одно.

Comment: Вот код: var random = new Random();
            int x, y;
            do
            {
                x = random.Next(1, 9);
                y = random.Next(1, 9);
            }
            while (x * 10 + y != (x+y)+Math.Pow((x+y),2));
            Console.WriteLine($"{x}{y}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{x}{y}");
            Console.ReadLine(); Что тут нужно добавить/изменить, чтобы вывести все значения?

Comment: Как минимум вывод в консоль сделать внутри цикла

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да вроде оба значения должны вывестись. А что у вас на консоль выводится? Покажите.

Comment: либо 12, либо 42, как повезёт

Comment: "Кому повезет, у того и петух снесет." Опишите словами что делает Ваш код. Еще напишите словами зачем у Вас две одинаковые строчки `Console.WriteLine($"{x}{y}");` одна за другой. Вы же нe надеетесь, что они выведут разные числа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я, кажется, понял вопрос.

Если использование `Random` не принципиально, то просто сделайте два вложенных цикла по `x` и по `y` и внутри циклов проверяйте ваше условие, как только выполнится - выводите на консоль значения `x` и `y`. Структура кода будет примерно такая:

```
for (var x = ...
{
    for (var y = ...
    {
        if (...
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{x}{y}");
        }
    }
}
```

Если же использование `Random` принципиально, то вам нужно будет сделать цикл `while` с условием, что счётчик найденных значений меньше 2 и в этом цикле брать случайные числа, проверять условие и добавлять найденные значения в список. Только проверять ещё нужно будет, что там ещё нет такой пары значений. Ну и счётчик при этом увеличивать. Вернее, счётчиком может служить и количество найденных пар значений в списке.

Весь код не пишу, потому что он во-первых совсем простой, а во-вторых потому, что учебные задания нужно делать самому.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать